# Angular Dropdown list validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am beginner to Angular

I have a task to add validation if Dropdown list is not selected I have to hide button

here is that code

button function

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" multiple (change)="onDealPriceFileChangeHandler($event)" accept=".xlsx"   />
```

Dropdown list code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="label" for="nights">Number of Nights</label>

   <nb-select fullWidth  placeholder="Select Number of Nights" >

 <nb-option *ngFor="let night of nights" [value]="night.value"
  (selectionChange)="nightHanlder(night.value)">{{night.name}}
  </nb-option>

 </nb-select>

 </div>
```

Night Array

```
nights = [
      { value: 1, name: '1 Night' },
      { value: 2, name: '2 Nights' },
      { value: 3, name: '3 Nights' },
]
```

night change function

```
nightHanlder(code){
   
this.selectNight=code;
}

I need to add an alert if dropdown is not selected
```

Comment: What is not working and are you getting any errors?

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]` : `<nb-select fullWidth [(ngModel)]="selectNight" placeholder="Select Number of Nights" >`. So the only is a `<button *ngIf="selectNigth">...</button>`. You needn't use `(change)` event, see the docs aboul ngModel: https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngModel

Comment: <div *ngIf="!(selectNight==0 || selectNight==null)">

<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" multiple (change)="onDealPriceFileChangeHandler($event)" accept=".xlsx"   />

</div>
then it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="!(selectNight==0 || selectNight==null)">

 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" multiple (change)="onDealPriceFileChangeHandler($event)" accept=".xlsx" /> 

</div>
```

then button not visible when loading

if you select Dropdown  button will visible

to show alert

```
 <div *ngIf="selectedNight==0 ||selectedNight==null">

   <div class="alert alert-danger">

     <strong>Select Number of Nights to Update PriceList </strong>

   </div>

 </div>
```